# C++ IDE feature: Synchronized viewing columns for headers and implementation files?

Tags: c++, ide, multiple-columns

Modern screens have large resolutions, fitting two or three columns of 80-column code easily. C++ basically requires that you separate your code into `.hpp` and `.cpp` files.

So, to utilize this space, why not automatically open the `.cpp` file in a second column when you open a `.hpp` file (and vice versa)? This obviously wouldn't work for extreme cases, although for a lot of projects there is a direct correspondence between the filenames that would be easy to determine. To me, this seems like a very reasonable use of this space, and it's hard to imagine it hasn't been done.

Is there an IDE that does this? A plugin? Or, why do you think it can't be done?

Answer (score 3):

If you're in Visual Studio, a plugin ([Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/)), which is already very nice to have for C++ projects has a similar feature. It's not completely automatic, but all you have to do is press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> and it will open the other file in the set. That is, if you're .hpp pressing the key will open the .cpp, and vice versa.

Their website demonstrates how this works in a video. It also works for things like XAML/Code Behind files, Windows Forms/Code files, etc. (Basically anywhere files operate in pairs, that key combo switches to the other file in the pair)

Comment: Ah, yes. I believe the IDE I currently use (Code::Blocks, don't use VS because it's not portable) has that feature as well (just checked--it's F11). I'm looking more for a way to effectively manage multiple columns, essentially just sets of tabs.

Thanks for reminding me about this though, the feature will help for the time being.

Comment: Why/How is VS "not portable"? Sure, the IDE itself only runs on Windows, but the code one creates with it is perfectly portable.

Comment: Maybe I should have explained a little better what I meant by portable. (Just didn't think that it mattered because VS wouldn't help.) I'm not referring to the code produced or single-platformedness, I just mean that I can't put VS on a flash drive and run it from there.